# Alternative of replication in internet disconnection period of time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, replication

Hi I'm looking for an alternative of merge replication that work without internet connection, something like red gate sql data compare but not in uniq direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to do something like utilize Change Data Capture but you will need to roll your own sql statements.

I'm confused why Merge Replication won't work for you here.  If you set the retention period high enough, it can go disconnected and pick up where it left off once connected again.

Comment: Thanks for reply, The big problem is to resolve a long internet disconnection periods knowing that both sites replication is installed between need to exchange their data ASAP